# onMouseLeave interaction with Chrome Password Storage Menu

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I built this menu with an OnMouseLeave property so that if you leave the menu space, the menu closes.
It works fine but,

as it is a login form menu, when you click on the input fields the chrome password manager pops in so that you can use any password/usernames chrome has, relating to the website. Normal, expected behaviour.

Of course, when you move the cursor towards the password manager, the OnMouseLeave triggers and the window closes.

How can I stop this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to both Morteza and Drew I found the answer

Indeed, the trick was to know what was targeting the mouse when activating the onMouseLeave events. Of course, it was the INPUT elements.

So, in the function that triggered the State change, I just set a conditional so that if the target was of TagName INPUT, the State change that closed the menu was to be aborted

Answer (score 1):

How about putting a condition if the input field is not null disable OnMouseLeave?

Comment: Thanks, you pointed me on the right direction! Actually, what I did is if the target that triggered the onMouseLeave was an input, cancel the menu closing down :-)

Answer (score 1):

please try this code, you can check out related target:

```
$("div").mouseleave(function(event){
  alert("relatedTarget is: " + event.relatedTarget);
});
```

Comment: I am working in React, I may be wrong but this code you provided  is JQuery?

Comment: sorry, okay, no problem, you can event pass to function and checking target, please share code.

Comment: thanks Morteza, found the answer. Actualy, checking the target via console log as you proposed  was key to the solution!